# Como puedo seleccionar el año de un date time

Tags: python, csv

Es que tengo un archivo csv donde tengo una lista fechas en string y las quiero a pasar a date .
ej:

```
Fecha = ['15/08/2019', '21/09/2021', '29/01/2020', '10/11/2020', '01/02/2018', '27/01/2018', '05/03/2020', '26/05/2020', '07/12/2021', '18/12/2020', '20/04/2019', '15/04/2020', '29/10/2018', '17/10/2020',
```

el problema es que cuando invoco la función a pasar a Date

```
fecha_dt = datetime.strptime(Fecha, '%d/%m/%Y')
```

si estoy bien , esta bien escrito pero me sale este error :

```
 File "C:\ProgramData\Miniconda3\envs\pythonProject\lib\_strptime.py", line 349, in _strptime
    raise ValueError("time data %r does not match format %r" %
ValueError: time data "['15/08/2019', '21/09/2021', '29/01/2020', '10/11/2020', '01/02/2018', '27/01/2018', '05/03/2020', '26/05/2020', '07/12/2021', '18/12/2020', '20/04/2019', '15/04/2020', '29/10/2018', '17/10/2020', '06/09/2
```

y también no se como solo imprimir solo los años , no quiero la tupla completa solo loso años, agradezco su ayuda pronta para este novato.

Comment: Existen varias formas una es usando la funcionalidad de pandas (si trabajas con ese) `columna = pd.to_datetime(columna)` también ouedes usar `apply`. Si no trabajas con pandas y tienes una lista puedes usar un list comprehension `fechas = [datetime.strptime(fecha, '%d/%m/%Y') for fecha in Fecha]`

Comment: El error que te da es porque pasas toda la lista como argumento, debes pasar una fecha individualmente. Esto es como indica @Christian en su segunda opción.